Strange error message after successful build
When building a C++ app with Qt6 I get the following error message after the build is finished:
/home/me/projects/Testapp/build> make -j24 CMakeLists.o
make: *** No rule to make target 'CMakeLists.o'.  Stop.
*** Failure: Exit code 2 ***

The previous output (before the error message) is:
/home/me/projects/Testapp/build> /usr/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release /home/me/projects/Testapp
-- Configuring done (0.1s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/me/projects/Testapp/build
*** Finished ***

But it becomes hidden by the error message. If I disturb CMakeLists (e.g. add a space) and rebuild the project once or twice the error message sometimes is shown briefly and then disappears. Looks like some kind of race condition.
My app is working as expected, but I am puzzled as to why the above error message appears after the build is finished. And I have no idea what is meant by 'CMakeLists.o'. Any suggestions?

CMake version: 3.28.3
cpp version 13.2.0
OS: Kubuntu 24.04
IDE: KDevelop 5.12.230805


"And I have no idea what is meant by 'CMakeLists.o'." - We too have no idea why do you specify CMakeLists.o as a target to build (make -j24 CMakeLists.o). Make too has no idea about that target, and emits quite clear error message No rule to make target 'CMakeLists.o'

I did not specify CMakeLists.o as a target. That's why I am pussled.
add_executable(Testapp ${Testapp_SRC})
target_link_libraries(Testapp Qt6::Charts ${Qt6Core} ${Qt6Gui} Qt6::Widgets jack)

The command line make -j24 CMakeLists.o is written by you. Or it is written by IDE, but IDE generates it according to options which is set by you. In that case you need to find out where you set this option (which denotes the target to be built) and fix it.

It has to do with KDevelop's "Build selection" and I can get around it by selecting the project I want to build, right click and select "Build". But I haven't been able to figure out exactly where "CMakeLists.o" stem from. If I manage to find out more I will report back.
